# What's the difference between msvcp120.dll and msvcp120_clr0400.dll?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, visual-c++-runtime

On the project I am working on we have access to `msvcp120_clr0400.dll` but not `msvcp120.dll` in the run-time environment, the same with `msvcr120.dll`and `msvcp120_clr0400.dll`. (The DLL's are in SysWOW64)

There is no way to install Visual C++ 2013 redistributable (Where these DLLs come from) because we have a limited package size for distribution. We cannot distrubute the DLLs ourselves for licencing reasons but copying and renaming each DLL to the name of the DLL we need on install works. Now this is obviously a hack but as far as I can tell these DLLs have minimal differences.

Copying and renaming DLLs is not ideal so I am thinking of creating a DLL proxy using something like https://github.com/zeroKilo/ProxyDllMaker and distributing the proxy named as the original DLL but all its calls just go to the DLL we know we have in SysWOW64.

**1. Does anyone have more info on the differences between these DLLs?**
(Does CLR stand for Common Language Runtime in this context perhaps?)
**2. Is there an alternative solution without installing Visual C++ 2013 redistributable?**

Comment: msvcp120_clr0400.dll is a private copy of the runtime DLL that is used by the .NET CLR.  Which is written in C++ so also has a dependency on the runtime DLLs.  Same story for msvcr120_clr0400.dll.  They are not useful to you, you don't have the import libraries for them.  And of course you would not want to have to install .NET just to get your program running.  Nor would you like Windows Update breaking your app when it updates .NET.  Deploy these DLLs yourself along with your own EXE and DLLs in the same install directory as your EXE.  If you only have a single EXE then do favor /MT.

Comment: Thanks Hans. We already install .NET which is why I know these DLLs will be installed. I see the problem with updates though. So you don't think there is a licencing problem with distributing these DLLs ourselves?

Comment: You cannot distribute these DLLs yourself, they are not listed in redist.txt.  This is not done to make your life miserable, it was done to prevent you shooting your leg off.  You have no idea if these DLLs might have been tweaked to support the CLR.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the non CLR versions. More explicitly can I distribute `msvcp120.dll` and `msvcr120.dll` with my application without the Visual C++ 2013 installer.

Comment: (Out application is .NET and one of the dependencies which we don't control is C++ so compiling with /MT would not be possible but we don't want the weight of the whole of Visual C++ redist 2013)

Comment: Answered my own question, thanks for the help Hans. https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-sdk-includes-u/